# Como criar botões com tamanho dinâmico em XML?

Tags: android-layout

Estou criando uma calculadora para android apenas com as funções básicas mesmo. Para isso estou escrevendo o código do Layout diretamente em XML, no entanto não consigo fazer com que os botões cresçam e ocupem a tela tanto ao virar o dispositivo quanto a ele normal estou a horas nisso.. Bem segue o código.

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Main">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/visor"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/visor"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDiv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Cls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn="
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="=" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Print do Layout atual.

[image: Print do Layout Atual]

Eu gostaria de deixar algo parecido com essa.

[image: Print do Layout Desejado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Havia um pequeno problema em seu `Layout`. Estava definindo sua `TableRow` sem o atributo `layout_width`, logo ele assumia como `wrap_content`, e estava usando o `layout_height` com `fill_parent`, que não funciona nesse caso.

Fiz as seguintes adaptações:

1. Troquei todos os `fill_parent's` para `match_parent`, porque ele foi depreciado, não muda nada, mas pode ser que em versões mais novas não funcione mais.
2. Dei pesos para suas linhas e deixei com altura dinâmica, usando o atributo `layout_weight` sendo `1` e `layout_height` sendo  para cada linha. Assim ele vai dividir a altura `0dp`. Assim toda altura do `TableLayout` vai ser dividida entre suas linhas de forma igual. Se adicionar mais linhas, não esqueça de atualizar o `weightSum`.
3. Coloquei seus `TextView's` ocupando todo espaço disponível para ele, usando o `layout_width` como `0dp` e `layout_height` sendo `match_parent`, e o mais importante o `layout_weight` como `1`. Assim ele distribui homogeneamente o espaço entre os `TextView's`.
4. Cuidado com o `btn=`, vai gerar erro ao compilar seus *resources*, use `btnEq` por exemplo.

Ao final seu layout ficará:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/visor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="FOCA"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDiv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="/" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMul"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="*" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSub"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Cls"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Clear" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEq"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSum"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="=" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

O resultado deve ser:

[image: Resultado da alteração no layout]

Comment: Opa, deu certo muito obrigado. Mas, hein o fill_parent está realmente depreciado? Eu estou tendo aula de android com um Java Champion, e tipo ele me garantiu que a diferença entre fill_parent e match_parent é apenas que o match só funciona em alguns tipos de layout. Ele está depreciado ou será? Agradeço.

Comment: Sim, ele foi renomeado na versão 8 (2.2): http://livroandroid.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/android-22-o-atributo-de-layout.html e http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html. Não esqueça que você pode controlar os pesos usando o atributo `layout_weight` e `weightSum`, caso queira customizar.