# "esticar" linha no tablelayout

Tags: android, xml

Bom, estou programando android, e construindo layouts do meu app.
Meu problema: não consigo fazer o layout do meu app se adequar verticalmente a dispositivos diferentes.

meu código xml:

```

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>
```

```

Queria que meus botoes almentassem de tamanho sozinhos quando a tela aumenta, na horizontal isso ja acontece devido ao tablelayout stretchColumns mas como faço pra isso ocorrer na verticar tbm?

obrigado!

Comment: Joannis, dê uma olhada na minha resposta para essa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33393/como-criar-bot%C3%B5es-com-tamanho-din%C3%A2mico-em-xml/33416#33416. Nela os botões se redimensionam conforme o tamanho da tela e orientação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, veja que você está utilizando TableRow.

O pai de TableRow deve ser TableLayout, pelas GuiLines do Google.

O seu TableLayout, com vários TableRows dentro, devem estar com fill ou match parent tanto na altura como na largura.

Se você deseja setar valor fixo para altura, como vi no seu exemplo, de 50dp, você pode definir um dimen.

Crie um arquivo Dimen na pasta values com:

50dp

Este será o atributo padrão.

Para outras resoluções, dimensões, densidades, etc...

Você pode criar outra pasta values, como values-small

E colocar esse mesmo dimen com valor menor, por exemplo.